# Symfony2: PdfBundle in prod leads to cache:clear failure

Tags: php, symfony, caching

Even with the [PdfBundle vendor's suggested use of `umask()`](https://github.com/psliwa/PdfBundle/issues/38) the following occurs when attempting to clear cache in (shared host) prod environment if a PDF has been created.  If a PDF has not been created, the error does not occur:

> [UnexpectedValueException]
>   FilesystemIterator::__construct(/home/projectmana/www2.projectmana.org/app/
>   cache/prod_old/zfcache-bd): failed to open dir: Permission denied

directory listing is:

```
drwx------   2 www-data    www-data      4096 Nov  9 17:15 zfcache-05
drwx------   2 www-data    www-data      4096 Nov  9 17:15 zfcache-18
drwx------   2 www-data    www-data      4096 Nov  9 17:15 zfcache-31
drwx------   2 www-data    www-data      4096 Nov  9 17:15 zfcache-bd
```

Is there a method in a shared host environment to eliminate this error?

Comment: Have you set up your cache permissions as outlined in the symfony2 [installation doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html)?

Comment: @mattexx: Absolutely.  Multiple times while testing.

Comment: Why is there a whitespace before your *cache* directory?

Comment: @sebbo: That's an artifact of copying all putty to clipboard to Notepad++ to SO. The server doesn't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only feasible alternative in this instance was to add the ability to clear the prod cache in a controller. This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815962/symfony-2-clear-cache-after-config-change) was the easiest to implement. Note that in a shared host environment it takes the system administrator to clear prod* directories before the controller action could be effective.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've just stumbled upon this issue. :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using another caching method like apc instead of files?

```
ps_pdf:
    cache:
      type: apc
```

https://github.com/psliwa/PdfBundle#configuration